# Python Jinja2 For Range

Tags: python, html, jinja2, bootstrap-modal

I'm learning python/jinja2 and I found a problem that I don't know how to solve it. I'm passing a list of data to Jinja, and with that list, it creates a table. This table is Ok and works fine. But when I want to pass one attribute of this list/table to a form, it looses the reference of the list and always sent the information about the first item of the list. Let me explain it better:

```
{% for value in listresult %}
<tr>
<td><center>{{ value.date }}</center></td>
{% set ident = value._id%}
<td>{{ident}}</td>
<td>
<form name="info_form" class="form-inline" action="/changetime1" method="post">
    <div id="enquirypopup" class="modal fade in" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content row">
                <div class="modal-header custom-modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">{{ident}}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#enquirypopup">Change</button>
</td>
{% endfor %}
```

The table creation at this point is correct. In the line 5, it prints one ID of each line in the table(Different ID). But when I ask to print the same variable, at Line 14, it always prints the "ident" of the first element of the list. It seems that when I call a form, it looses the reference of which element we are on the list.

[Result Table - Pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd8cv.png)

So, doesn't matter which element of the list I click(Button "Change" line 20), the ID that comes in the pop up is always the first element.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with HTML element ids. Since you're creating each form with the same ID (`#enquirypopup`), your browser is only returning the first element in the page—i.e. the first time it sees the `#enquirypopup` id*.

A quick workaround would be setting the ids with the jinja `ident` variable like so:

```
 <div id="enquirypopup_{{ ident }}" class="modal fade in" role="dialog">...</div>
```

and

```
<button type="button" class="btn..." data-toggle="modal" data-target="#enquirypopup_{{ ident }}">Change</button>
```

But there are countless other solutions using different selectors.

---

*This is not standardized behavior and differs across browsers, another reason why it's [bad practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)